# Why is not equal represented by ~= in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

This one of the things that has always bothered me about Matlab. I understand why arrays start at 1 and not at 0 like in any other programming language, but why is `!=` `~=` in Matlab?

Comment: Why is the sky represented by red on Mars?  Because it's Mars, and not Earth.

Comment: You may want to write "like in most other programming languages". One other language that starts indexing at 1 that comes to my mind is LUA.

Comment: Interestingly, Octave, which is the open source clone of Matlab, does accept != (in addition to ~=), as well as !x (in addition to ~x).

Comment: Matlab is from the 1970s. Things may have been different on several levels: actual prevalence of languages; discoverability of such statistics as prevalence of languages; whether convergence of syntax was a concern weighed against readability by mathematicians. However, it seems that adding in `!=` today would cause absolutely no problems, especially given Octave does it.

Comment: FORTAN arrays start at 1, and the first MATLAB was written in FORTRAN for scientist that were working mostly in FORTRAN.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The tilde character (~) is generally used as the bitwise NOT operator.
As the ! character is reserved for an other usage (OS command), I guess it's not a bad choice.

Answer (score 11):

In mathematical logic ~ is an old-fashioned way to write ¬

Answer (score 2):

In logic tilde can mean "not", which may be confusing as in math tilde can be "equivalence" or "approx". However, it is found on more keyboards than the less ambiguous ¬. Watch out, as tilde can also mean bitwise not :)

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody for your answers. They all answer my question for some part, so what should I do? Can I mark all answers as "answered"?

Comment: @Ingo. Pick whichever seems the most complete. In a tie, pick whichever of the tied answers was earliest. If still stuck, just go for whoever you think has the best photo (this is how many vote in elections). If still stuck; write a pseudo random number generator, test its quality against NIST security tests, improve it until it passes, write a paper on a mathematical discovery you made it the course of doing so, receive a small but prestigious prize for your contribution to the state of the art, and then use the PRNG to pick an answer to select. Well, that or just picking one arbitrarily.

Comment: in a tie breaker, go for the person with the lowest rep!

Answer (score 0):

Why is `.not..eq.` represented by `~=` ?  For the same reason that it is not represented as `=!=` or `/=` or any of the hundred and one other conventions used in programming languages.

And the twiddle, or `~`, is widely used in logic texts to mean `NOT`.